# Optimizing MySQL LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

My goal is to select articles where the `primary_category_id` (`articles` table) or any of the 
secondary categories (`articles_secondary_categories` join table) are a given value. In this example query, category 1. I tried using other types of joins but the caveat here is that an article might not have any secondary categories.

```
SELECT DISTINCT articles.* 
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN articles_secondary_categories AS categories 
    ON categories.article_id = articles.id
WHERE 
(
    primary_category_id = 1
    OR
    categories.category_id = 1
)
    AND articles.state = "published"
    AND edition_id = 1

ORDER BY publish_at DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Any help optimizing this or alternatives are welcome. In a DB with 4k `articles` and 7k `articles_secondary_categories` (not categories) it takes 5 seconds to run this query.

Comment: What execution time result without WHERE (...) clause?

Comment: your question is how can you optimize this query to run in less than 5 secs?

Comment: Is DISTINCT really necessary here?

Comment: If you don't have an index on (categories.articles_id, categories.category_id), you should add it.

Comment: Do you need the `DISTINCT`? This is going to perform a `GROUP BY` on all of the fields you are returning which _could_ cause a slowdown. What indexes do you have on the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the query on the secondary categories:

```
(SELECT articles.* 
FROM articles
WHERE primary_category_id = 1)
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT articles.*
FROM articles_secondary_categories AS categories 
JOIN articles ON (categories.article_id = articles.id)
WHERE categories.category_id = 1
GROUP BY articles_id)
ORDER BY publish_at DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

It should give you a decent speed boost - just make sure you index categories.articles_id

Comment: This was the fastest but we ultimately ended up restructuring our tables to better suit the queries we were doing.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `OR` in your where clause. Optimizers usually don't use indexes with `OR` predicates.

Try moving the `categories.category_id = 1` into the join condition:

```
SELECT articles.* 
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN articles_secondary_categories AS categories 
    ON categories.article_id = articles.id and categories.category_id = 1
WHERE 1 in (ifnull(categories.category_id, primary_category_id), primary_category_id)
AND articles.state = "published"
AND edition_id = 1
ORDER BY publish_at DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The key to this query is `1 in (ifnull(categories.category_id, primary_category_id), primary_category_id)`, which says "if we got a join to categories, use that in the list, otherwise use the primary_category_id, and in all cases use the primary_category_id.